# Center TabBar button going to back

Tags: ios, swift, segue, tabbar

I have created a centre TabBar button by subclassing UITabBarController and adding a bigger button to the centre.

[image]

Now when i go to an item in my menu, which is just a static TableViewController embedded in a ViewController the button will not hide with the TabBar, where i have just set the bottom bar to hide on push within interface builder.

Static Table View

[image]

Button Still Shown when menu item page loaded.  This is just an empty ViewController with a 'show' segue from the static TableViewCell

[image]

Hid Bottom Bar Selected.

[image]

i also have a problem when going back to the menu and the TabBar is displayed again.  The button is now behind the TabBar.

[image]

------EDIT-------

I revised my outlook and have added the following to my TabBarController class

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    if self.homeButton != nil {
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.homeButton)

        for test in self.view.subviews {
            if let subView = test as? UITabBar {
                if subView.isHidden == true {
                    self.homeButton.isHidden = true
                } else {
                    self.homeButton.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

its just a little slow, there is a delay of about 1 second from when the view changes to when the button is wither hidden or brought to the front.

Any better ideas about how to display this faster?